# Uncharted 4 Multiplayer Survival 3-Stars

Tags: uncharted-4

When playing Uncharted 4 Survival, I have played on both Light and Moderate levels.

When I played on the Light Level, I completed the first stage without dying, neither did the AI playing beside me. Yet, I still only got 1 star. How do you get the 3-stars in all the stages?

And also, is it true that you get a special symbol next to your multiplayer name if you get 3-stars on all stages of any level? I am currently finding that hard to do, even on the light level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light mode won't give you the symbol. Only moderate and upwards.

To get 2 or 3 stars, you have to complete the levels in a certain time. Each level has its own and you'll see them in the menu.

Getting 3 stars requires teamwork from real players. The AI is useless in getting anything. Get some excellent players and complete the levels with them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does dying affect the number of stars you get?

Comment: Also, does that mean it's difficult getting 3 stars with AI?

Answer (score 1):

Dying only affects the stars in a time consuming way. The only thing you have worry about, is that you pass each level before the time for each star runs out.

With AI, I think you have a chance of getting 1 star with moderate difficulty, tops.